# Angular 2 Typescript inheratance state-pattern issue

Tags: inheritance, angular, typescript, extends, typescript2.0

I'm uning Typescript inheritance to implement a state pattern but I'm getting a runtime error when I new up the superclass. Hoping to find out why or what's wrong, thanks.

Working plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/XScXR4?p=preview

vehicle.ts
    import { Car } from "./car";

```
export class Vehicle {

  description: string = "Generic Vehicle";

  swap(app: AppComponent): void {
     app.vehicle = this.isCar(app) ? new Vehicle() : new Car();
  }

  /* Just a helper for demo purposes */
  private isCar(app: AppComponent) {
    return app.vehicle instanceof Car;
  }

}
```

car.ts

```
import { Vehicle } from "./vehicle";

export class Car extends Vehicle {
  description: string = "Car";
}
```

It's basically a state-pattern. Any vehicle be it type 'Vehicle' or 'Car' can swap the instance in the 'AppComponent'

app.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Vehicle }  from "./vehicle";
import { Car }  from "./car";

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  vehicle: Vehicle;

  swap(): void {
    this.vehicle.swap(this);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    //No problems works perfectly
    //this.vehicle = new Car();

     //Error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined(…)
    this.vehicle = new Vehicle();
  }

}
```

If I initialize with a 'Car' instance (subtype) there is no problem.

If I initialize with a 'Vehicle' instance (supertype) I get a JS runtime error

```
Error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined(…)
```

I'd really like to know why because this seems like a legitimate thing to do.

What am I doing wrong here?

In the [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/XScXR4?p=preview), in app.component.ts just replace the

```
this.vehicle = new Car()
```

with

```
 this.vehicle = new Vehicle()
```

to see the issue.

Thanks very much
John

Comment: You have circular dependenciy in your imports https://plnkr.co/edit/LFM1VS?p=preview

Comment: Thanks, you've given me a way to solve it. The circular reference thing however I'm not sure of. Perhaps under the hood after compilation but it doesn't explain why I can do new Car() but not new Vehicle() because both have references to each other.